# How to make paths to fill green all the time when there is mouseover using d3

Tags: d3.js

d3 loaded external svg which contains closed paths,Code is highlighting green fill only once per each path from the refresh. Is it possible to make green fills for all the mouseovers.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<script type="text/javascript" src="./d3.min.js"></script>
<title>svg and d3</title>
</head>
<body>
<script type="text/javascript">
d3.xml("t.svg")
      .mimeType("image/svg+xml")
      .get(function(error, xml) {
if (error) throw error;
document.body.appendChild(xml.documentElement);
d3.selectAll('path.tel')
.on("mouseover", function(d) {
d3.select(this).style("fill", "green");
})
.on("mouseout", function(d) {
d3.select(this).style("fill", "none");
});
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you provide more information (like a demo, the version of d3 you're using) and explicit your question, with an example maybe?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/yd2cwn78/

Comment: What do you want to do exactly
I'm not sure to understand the question

Comment: On each mouseover i am expecting a green/red fill , but it is happening only once.

Comment: like this https://jsfiddle.net/oeuc96mj/1/ ? (sorry for the late answer, I had a lot of work)

Comment: solved JackRed.Thank you.